# 'CHAINLINK_VERSION' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I try install chainlink local on my windows from https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink
but got problem can't use command 'chainlink' as detail below.Please help guide me how to fix it.

```
PS C:\Users\Ploy\Documents\moralis\chainlink> make install
. . .
@chainlink/contracts
 | Solidity 0.8.6, 0.8.11 are not fully supported yet. You can still use Hardhat, but some features, like stack traces, might not work correctly.
 | Generating typings for: 99 artifacts in dir: ./typechain for target: ethers-v5
 | Successfully generated 168 typings!
 | Compilation finished successfully
Done in 60.09s.
CHAINLINK_VERSION="@7b1d51a514024b0c5aa011269aed1c6cbfed39fb" yarn workspace @chainlink/operator-ui build
'CHAINLINK_VERSION' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [GNUmakefile:58: operator-ui] Error 1
```

My environment

windows 10

nvm 12.22.10

solc version 0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Emscripten.clang

go version go1.17.5 windows/amd64

psql (PostgreSQL) 14.1

Comment: What version of yarn are you using?